# Nuxt: wrong Axios base URL in client side API requsets

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have set axios Base_url like this in Nuxt config

```
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
  },
```

the problem is that when i requset api in client side, axios uses default base_url ,
i mean it sends requests to http://localhost:3000/ not to my backend server .
But for requests in server side everything is ok .

the below pic shows client side request .
[image]

Comment: Can you show the code used to make the `axios` request?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Up proxy for the APIs . (In network tab the url will show up as it is shown in the question image)

```
  axios: {
   baseURL: process.env.API_URL, // Must be base url
   proxy: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
  }
  proxy:
     process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
       ? {
           '/': {
                  target: process.env.API_URL,
                  changeOrigin: true,
                  logLevel: 'debug',
                  secure: false
                }
         }
       : false,
```